# Pipe results of locate into rm

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, rm

I tried running

```
locate *.orig | xargs rm
```

but it said `No such file or directory`

I've seen ways to do it with `find` but locate returns the full path to the object so it should be possible

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If filenames contain spaces you should use

```
locate -0 $something | xargs -0 rm
```

From [`locate` man page](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locate.1.html):

> `-0`, `--null` Separate the entries on output using the ASCII NUL character instead of writing each entry on a separate line.  This option is designed for interoperability with the --null option of GNU xargs(1).

or

```
locate $something | while read f; do rm "$f"; done
```

Also, you should protect `*.orig` with quotes, to avoid the shell expansion, and pass it to locate untouched.

Comment: What do you mean by "shell expansion"?

Comment: +1 for your second example. I always use `| while read` since my home directory is full of files with spaces.

Comment: @Soldier.moth: if in the current folder there are files corresponding to the pattern `*.orig`, the shell will expand the pattern to, say, `file1.orig file2.orig ...`, so that `locate` will not see the exact string `*.orig` as it should.

Comment: Also to grep locate output you can then `tr '\n' '\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

It's `xargs` not `xarg`

Comment: That's what I meant was typing question from memory thank you though.

Comment: Oh, ok. It looked like the error you'd get putting an incorrect command after |

Answer (score 0):

The command `locate *.orig | xargs rm` does work actually but what was happening was that `locate` was finding `*.orig` files in the trash can and `rm` spits out the error `No such file or directory` when trying to delete files in the trash can.

Comment: You should add information as a "comment" to the original answer, or you can edit the original answer. This is not an answer to your own question.

Comment: It is an answer to my question the reason I was getting the error was because locate was finding *.orig files in the trash can and rm couldn't delete them. I accepted your answer and voted up both other answers because they were well written and might help someone who comes along later.

Answer (score 0):

locate doesn't do the globbing, but the shell does. The shell expands *.orig to what it finds in the current directory which matches *.orig.

Just use

```
locate .orig
```

and if that gets you what you need

```
locate .orig | xargs rm
```

or, as enzotib mentioned

```
locate -0 .orig | xargs -0 rm
```

if you have Whitespace in the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

A trick : Save all paths in tmp file . then , Loop on it:

```
#!/bin/bash
locate .orig /tmp/tmp.txt
while read line
do
    pth=$line
    rm "$pth" 
done < /tmp/tmp.txt

rm -rf /tmp/tmp.txt
```